# Let $ \ B \ $ be the matrix obtained from the matrix $ \ A \ $ by interchanging the $ \ i^{th} \ $ and $ \ j^{th} \ $ rows

Tags: matrices

Let $ \ B \ $ be the matrix obtained from the matrix $ \ A \ $ by interchanging the $ \ i^{th} \ $ and $ \ j^{th} \ $ rows , then show that

$ B=MA \ $ , where $ \ M \ $ is the matrix obtained from the identity matrix $ \ I \ $ by interchanging $ \ i^{th} \ $ and $ \ j^{th} \ $ rows.

**Answer:**

Let $ \ A=[a_1 \ \ a_2 \ \ .... \ \ a_i  \ \ ... .\ \ a_j .... \ a_n ]^T \ $ , where  $ \ a_k , \ \ k=1,2,3,....,n \ $ are row vectors of $ \ A \ $

Then,

$  B=[a_1 \ \ a_2 \ \ ....a_j \ \ .... \ \ a_i \ \ .... \ a_n  ]^T=[e_{ji}]  [a_1 \ \ a_2 \ \ .... \ \ a_i  \ \ ... .\ \ a_j .... \ a_n ]^T \ = MA$ ,

where $ e_{ij} =\delta_j^i \ $

**Am I right?**

**Help me out**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$
A_1=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
A_{11},&A_{12},&A_{13},& \cdots ,& A_{1n}
\end{array}\right),
\\
A_2=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
A_{21},&A_{22},&A_{23},& \cdots ,& A_{2n}
\end{array}\right),
\\
A_3=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
A_{31},&A_{32},&A_{33},& \cdots ,& A_{3n}
\end{array}\right),
\\
\vdots
\\
\\
\vdots
\\
A_n=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
A_{n1},&A_{n2},&A_{n3},& \cdots ,& A_{nn}
\end{array}\right),
$$
the rows of matrix 
$$
A=\left\lgroup \begin{array}{ccc c c}
A_{11}& A_{12}& A_{13}& \cdots &  A_{1n}\\
A_{21}& A_{22}& A_{23}& \cdots &  A_{2n}\\ 
A_{31}& A_{32}& A_{23}& \cdots &  A_{3n}\\ 
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots &  \vdots\\
A_{n1}& A_{n2}& A_{n3}& \cdots &  A_{nn}\\  
\end{array}\right\rgroup
=
\left\lgroup \begin{array}{c}
A_1\\
A_2\\ 
A_3\\ 
\vdots\\
A_n\\  
\end{array}\right\rgroup
$$

Let 
$$
e_1=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
1,&0,&0,& \cdots ,& 0
\end{array}\right),
\\
e_2=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
0,&1,&0,& \cdots ,& 0
\end{array}\right),
\\
e_3=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
0,&0,&1,& \cdots ,& 0
\end{array}\right),
\\
\vdots
\\
\\
\vdots
\\
e_n=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
0,&0,&0,& \cdots ,& 1
\end{array}\right),
$$
the rows of matrix identity 
$$
I=\left\lgroup \begin{array}{ccc c c}
1& 0& 0& \cdots &  0\\
0& 1& 0& \cdots &  0\\ 
0& 0& 1& \cdots &  0\\ 
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots &  \vdots\\
0& 0& 0& \cdots &  1\\  
\end{array}\right\rgroup
=
\left\lgroup \begin{array}{c}
e_1\\
e_2\\ 
e_3\\ 
\vdots\\
e_n\\  
\end{array}\right\rgroup
$$
Note that
$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
1,&0,&0,& \cdots ,& 0
\end{array}\right)
\left\lgroup \begin{array}{ccc c c}
A_{11}& A_{12}& A_{13}& \cdots &  A_{1n}\\
A_{21}& A_{22}& A_{23}& \cdots &  A_{2n}\\ 
A_{31}& A_{32}& A_{23}& \cdots &  A_{3n}\\ 
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots &  \vdots\\
A_{n1}& A_{n2}& A_{n3}& \cdots &  A_{nn}\\  
\end{array}\right\rgroup
=
\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
A_{11},&A_{12},&A_{13},& \cdots ,& A_{1n}
\end{array}\right)
\\
\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
0,&1,&0,& \cdots ,& 0
\end{array}\right)
\left\lgroup \begin{array}{ccc c c}
A_{11}& A_{12}& A_{13}& \cdots &  A_{1n}\\
A_{21}& A_{22}& A_{23}& \cdots &  A_{2n}\\ 
A_{31}& A_{32}& A_{23}& \cdots &  A_{3n}\\ 
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots &  \vdots\\
A_{n1}& A_{n2}& A_{n3}& \cdots &  A_{nn}\\  
\end{array}\right\rgroup
=
\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
A_{21},&A_{22},&A_{23},& \cdots ,& A_{2n}
\end{array}\right)
\\
\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
0,&0,&1,& \cdots ,& 0
\end{array}\right)
\left\lgroup \begin{array}{ccc c c}
A_{11}& A_{12}& A_{13}& \cdots &  A_{1n}\\
A_{21}& A_{22}& A_{23}& \cdots &  A_{2n}\\ 
A_{31}& A_{32}& A_{23}& \cdots &  A_{3n}\\ 
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots &  \vdots\\
A_{n1}& A_{n2}& A_{n3}& \cdots &  A_{nn}\\  
\end{array}\right\rgroup
=
\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
A_{31},&A_{32},&A_{33},& \cdots ,& A_{3n}
\end{array}\right)
\\
\vdots
\\
\vdots
\\
\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
0,&0,&0,& \cdots ,& 1
\end{array}\right)
\left\lgroup \begin{array}{ccc c c}
A_{11}& A_{12}& A_{13}& \cdots &  A_{1n}\\
A_{21}& A_{22}& A_{23}& \cdots &  A_{2n}\\ 
A_{31}& A_{32}& A_{23}& \cdots &  A_{3n}\\ 
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots &  \vdots\\
A_{n1}& A_{n2}& A_{n3}& \cdots &  A_{nn}\\  
\end{array}\right\rgroup
=
\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
A_{n1},&A_{n2},&A_{n3},& \cdots ,& A_{nn}
\end{array}\right)
$$
We have for $j>i$
$$
\left\lgroup \begin{array}{ccc c c}
A_{11}& A_{12}& A_{13}& \cdots &  A_{1n}\\
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots &  \vdots\\
A_{j1}& A_{j2}& A_{j3}& \cdots &  A_{jn}\\
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots &  \vdots\\ 
A_{i1}& A_{i2}& A_{i3}& \cdots &  A_{in}\\ 
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots &  \vdots\\
A_{n1}& A_{n2}& A_{n3}& \cdots &  A_{nn}\\  
\end{array}\right\rgroup
=
\left\lgroup\begin{array}{c}
e_1A\\ \vdots \\ e_jA \\ \vdots \\e_iA \\\vdots\\ e_nA
\end{array}\right\rgroup
=
\left\lgroup\begin{array}{c}
e_1\\ \vdots \\ e_j \\ \vdots \\e_i \\ \vdots \\e_n
\end{array}\right\rgroup
\left\lgroup \begin{array}{ccc c c}
A_{11}& A_{12}& A_{13}& \cdots &  A_{1n}\\
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots &  \vdots\\
A_{i1}& A_{i2}& A_{i3}& \cdots &  A_{in}\\
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots &  \vdots\\ 
A_{j1}& A_{j2}& A_{j3}& \cdots &  A_{jn}\\ 
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots &  \vdots\\
A_{n1}& A_{n2}& A_{n3}& \cdots &  A_{nn}\\  
\end{array}\right\rgroup
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you left multiply an $ n \times m$  matrix $A$ by a $n \times n$ matrix $M$, then each row of $M$ acts on the rows of $A$.  So if the matrix $M$ has a row with all zeros but $1$ in the $i-th$ column, it just picks out the $i-th$ row of $A$.  Hence a matrix that interchanges the $i-th$ and $j-th$ rows of $I_n$ (the $n \times n$ identity matrix)  will simply interchange the corresponding rows of $A$.

The key is that multiplying $A$ on the left operates on its rows.  (Multiplying on the right by some $m \times p$ matrix operates on the columns of $A$.)

Let $M^{(ij)}$ denote the matrix that one gets by interchanging the $i-th$ and $j-th$ rows of the identity matrix.  These kinds of matrices are very useful in linear algebra, and they can be used to prove many properties of determinants.